# How can i define coordinates of rectangle if i know two middle coordinates?

Tags: geometry

coordinates of black points is known. width of rectangle is 10. how can i define all coordinates of rectangle?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc2oz.jpg

Comment: You probably the coordinates of the corners ?

Comment: yep, coordinates of corners

Answer (score 0):

[image]

By width = 10, I assume the shortest side has a width of 10. Half of its width is therefore 5.

Lets first find the vector going from L to R, then normalize it to have length 1 and stretch it to length 5. Lets call this vector A. A can be calculated as follows: A = 5*(R-L) / |R-L|.

Now, A can be rotated 90 degrees clockwise or counterclockwise and be applied to L, to obtain S or W, respectively.

In the same way, A can be rotated 90 degrees clockwise or counter clockwise and be applied to R, to botain E or N, respectively.

That is:

S = L + A * Rotate(-90)

W = L + A * Rotate(90)

E = R + A * Rotate(-90)

N = R + A  * Rotate(90)

where Rotate(x) is the rotation matrix for rotating a vector x degrees counter clockwise, as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

The complete calculations:

Ax = 5 * (Rx-Lx) / sqrt((Rx-Lx)^2 + (Ry-Ly)^2)

Ay = 5 * (Ry-Ly) / sqrt((Rx-Lx)^2 + (Ry-Ly)^2)

S = (Lx + Ay, Ly - Ax)

W = (Lx - Ay, Ly + Ax)

E = (Rx + Ay, Ry - Ax)

N = (Rx - Ay, Ry + Ax)

Answer (score 0):

Let's M0, M1 are black points.

```
//vector M0-M1
mx = M1.X - M0.X
my = M1.Y - M0.Y

//perpendicular vector
px = - my
py = mx

//it's length
lp =Sqrt(px*px + py*py)

 //unit perp. vector
 upx = px / lp
 upy = py / lp

 //vertices
 V1.x = M0.X + 5 * upx
 V1.y = M0.Y + 5 * upy
 V2.x = M0.X - 5 * upx
 V2.y = M0.Y - 5 * upy
 //the same for M1 and V3, V4
```